# Why a variable is seen in the loop and is not seen outside the loop?

Tags: java, initialization, compiler-errors

I have the following code:

```
    String serviceType;
    ServiceBrowser tmpBrowser;
    for (String playerName: players) {
        serviceType = "_" + playerName + "._tcp";
        tmpBrowser = BrowsersGenerator.getBrowser(serviceType);
        tmpBrowser.browse();
        System.out.println(tmpBrowser.getStatus());
    }       
    System.out.println(tmpBrowser.getStatus());
```

The compiler complains about the last line. It writes "variable tmpBrowser might not been initialized". If I comment the last line the compile does not complain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are no `players`, then the `tmpBrowser` won't be initialized at any way. The compiler can't predict if there are any players or not. Also, in contrary to fields (class/instance variables declared outside method blocks), local variables (declared inside method blocks) won't be preinitialized with default values. You need to make the compiler happy by preinitializing it yourself:

```
ServiceBrowser tmpBrowser = null;
```

(don't forget to do a nullcheck before `getStatus()`, else you may risk a NPE).

Answer (score 1):

If the number of elements in the `players` variable is zero, the loop won't be executed, thus the `tmpBrowser` variable will never have been initialized (not even the `null` value) when the `System.out.println()` call is executed.

The only way to solve the error is to give the tmpBrowser variable a meaningful default (if only even to have `null`, but you'll still have a `NullPointerException` raised by the `tmpBrowser.getStatus()` in that case) if you can't get rid of the last `System.out.println(tmpBrowser.getStatus());` call.

Comment: It won't be null. It will remain uninitialized. That's why it can't compile.

Comment: @BalusC: I don't understand your comment. From wikipedia: In Java, fields of classes and objects that do not have an explicit initializer and elements of arrays are automatically initialized with the default value for their type (false for boolean, 0 for all numerical types, null for all reference types). Local variables in Java must be definitely assigned to before they are accessed, or it is a compile error.

Comment: @BalusC Certainly, the code won't actually run, hence the compile error, but if it *were* to run, the tmpBrowser variable's value might be null (the value of any non-initialized variable), hence the compiler error.

Comment: @LB and Peter Nix: you're confusing fields with local variables.

Comment: ok, i think i misunderstand the "objects that do not have an explicit initializer". (i don't confuse fields and local variables..really.. :-) ).

Comment: @BalusC you're absolutely right in the initialization difference between fields and local variables, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Because it really might not been initialized if players is an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you never enter the for loop say when the `players` array is empty, the variable `tempBrowser` will remain ***uninitialized***. So to overcome this you need to ensure that `tempBrowser` has a value assigned to it irrespective of the loop. Something like:

```
ServiceBrowser tmpBrowser = null;
```

before the loop will help.